# Doctrine QueryBuilder order by the amount of 2 fields

Tags: doctrine-orm

I would like to calculate the amount of 2 fields, and ordering the results by.
The querybuilder ends like this:

```
$qb->orderBy('(e.likesCnt + e.additionalLikes)', 'DESC')
```

and I got this error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("[Syntax Error] line 0, col 264: Error: Expected end of string, got
>   'e'")

Last try was when:

```
$qb->select('e, (e.likesCnt + e.additionalLikes) AS totalLikes')
$qb->orderBy('totalLikes', 'DESC')
```

but it brings an error too

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("[Semantical Error] line 0, col 290 near 'totalLikes DESC,': Error:
>   'totalLikes' is not defined.")

Any solutions gratefully accepted :-)

**Update:**
Well, alias is not allowed in the "orderby" statement. Also, if one of your field is null then the amount will be null too, that's cause the semantical error. My solution is:

```
$qb->orderBy('((e.likesCnt + e.additionalLikes)+0)', 'DESC')
```

In this case, the ordering will be applicated without semantical error and gets the correct results.

Comment: Add your commulative result to your selects (eg. `->select('e.likesCnt + e.additionalLikes', 'totalLikes')` and order by that (`->orderBy('totalLikes', 'DESC');`)

Comment: Can you show all queries?

Comment: @ImanaliMamadiev thanx for the help, but the question is updated with my solution

Comment: @Roland, Why you didn't use my answer? or not work my answer?

Comment: @ImanaliMamadiev your answer is wrong. There is the reason in the first comment. Please check it yourself

Answer (score 1):

The select method is getting parameter as array, for example:

```
$qb->select('e', '(e.likesCnt + e.additionalLikes) AS totalLikes')
$qb->orderBy('totalLikes', 'DESC')
```

Comment: you've created an alias "totalLikes", but you can't use aliases in "orderby"

Comment: @Roland  Try it with `AS HIDDEN totalLikes`